# Bigquery dataset using pub/sub subscription

Tags: python, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

Trying to create a dataset using pub/sub subscription message. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery. This one provides how to write message to the table, but how can I create a dataset using the message. For example - if I have this is test1 in my subscription, then I should be able to take the message(test1) and create a dataset based on that message. Just an empty dataset, no table needed. I have done all the research and didn't see any solution from google.

Comment: If you have a message, you can plug a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run that do the job. If you have Terraform, you can create a dataset in advance (but it requires to know the dataset in advance, and not ad-hoc when a message comes in). What's your issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a Cloud Function when the message is published on the topic with Pub Sub triggers :

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub

```
gcloud functions deploy python-pubsub-function \
--gen2 \
--runtime=python310 \
--region=REGION \
--source=. \
--entry-point=subscribe \
--trigger-topic=YOUR_TOPIC_NAME
```

You can also check this link :

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

The Cloud Function can use Python client to create your dataset, here an example :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

import base64

import functions_framework

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def subscribe(cloud_event):
    dataset_id_from_topic =  base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]).decode()

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # Construct a full Dataset object to     send to the API.
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id_from_topic)

    # TODO(developer): Specify the geographic location where the dataset should reside.
    dataset.location = "US"

    # Send the dataset to the API for creation, with an explicit timeout.
    # Raises google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict if the Dataset already
    # exists within the project.
    dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset, timeout=30)  

    # Make an API request.
    print("Created dataset {}.   {}".format(client.project, dataset.dataset_id))
```

Comment: So first part is i am creating a push subscription to push it to cloud function and then it will read it to create the dataset. I don't wan't to create the dataset before, the dataset naming should be from the message I retrieve

Comment: I edited my answer to show the code logic in a subscribe function. This function read the message from the Pub Sub as dataset ID and create the dataset from this ID.

Comment: can we get the project name by the id, is there any python functionality or api

Comment: Why do you need to get the project name ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects. I got it, here is the answer in here

Comment: Any idea regarding this one - https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/how-can-i-force-an-immediate-run-of-a-job-trigger